# Removing edit or new item button from a SharePoint 2013 list

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

I am having a list in sharepoint 2013. In one scenario I want the user to just enter a new item into a sharepoint list without editing any previous items.Whereas, in second scenario I just want the user to edit a list without being able to add any new item.

From what I explored this is not posssible using any out of the box feature.

The four .aspx files newform, displayform, editform and allitems form don't seem to contain any option for resolving this.

Does it require using any javascript code? How can it be done?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVEIm.png

Comment: You have 40 tabs open in Chrome. Insane.

Answer (score 1):

Just a tweak , create 2 custom permission levels. First one, has rights to add new/View  item but no Edit/Delete item permissions. Second, level will have permission to edit item but no permission to add item. Try assigning the user these 2 permission level according to your scenarios, ie Give user first permission level when you want him to only add items and remove first and assign only second permission level when you want user to only edit item.

Answer (score 0):

If yoy want to remove "add new" and "edit" feature, simply set "Toolbar Type" to "No Toolbar"

Answer (score 0):

For your second scenario, an out of the box workaround: To allow users to only  edit the list items without the option to add new items you can setup a public view with any grouping (this disables Quick Edit), then add a "mandatory field" (I use row #) that will not be visible in any public view, edit the "edit item" form with InfoPath and remove the "mandatory field". Even if users try to add a new item they will not be able to save, only edit existing items. Simple and doesn't require any coding of any kind nor permissions.